# Where is django installed windows?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to find the file Django admin but I can't find it. What command can I use to find where this is located? Thanks.

P.S I am using windows 10

Comment: "the *file* Django admin"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install django according to [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/windows/)? In that case, modules installed via `pip` (that includes django, which in turn includes the admin) will reside in `%USERPROFILE%\Envs`, with `%USERPROFILE%` being `%SystemDrive%\Documents and Settings\{your username}`

Answer (score 0):

From your terminal, type:

```
python -c "import django; print(django.__path__)"
```